# Taking Random Samples in Excel

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to take 80 random samples in Microsoft Excel 100 times. I can take it one time in 80 rows but I am not getting how to do it 100 times

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps

1. Activate data analisis tools

[image: file -> options ->]

[image: Ok]

2. Now select sampling

[image]

Then select what data do you want sample, number of samples (100) and output range

[image]

Good luck